# How can I read/convert SAS Gov't Data files on a MAC?

Tags: sas, file-conversion

There are gov't data files: http://www.cdc.gov/EpiInfo/

Available in this weird SAS format. How can I convert them into XML/CSV, something much simpler that can be read by scripts/etc.???

Comment: Isn't EpiInfo an application program, not data files?

Comment: EpiInfo is an epidemiology analysis program developed by CDC;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, so i made a simple SAS data viewer. You download it from the downloads section here: http://code.google.com/p/sasquatch

It has alot of the same features as SAS Universal Viewer, but its still a work in progress.

You need to have Adobe AIR installed, you can get that on the adobe website.

Answer (score 1):

Are the data in the SAS XPORT (.xpt) or .sas7bdat format?

Answer (score 1):

For future reference,  SAS XPORT files can be read and written using the 'SASxport' package for R (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SASxport/index.html).

Comment: I couldn't resolve the dependencies for this package.

Answer (score 0):

(Already posted this to [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/54434/how-can-i-convert-sas-data-files-into-something-simple-like-csv-data/54513#54513))

SAS Institute (the company that makes SAS) produces a [viewer for SAS data sets](http://www.sas.com/apps/demosdownloads/sassysview_PROD_8.2_sysdep.jsp?packageID=000176).

Note that SAS program files usually have the extension `.sas`, whereas the data files themselves usually have the extension `.sas7bdat`.

(**EDIT**: I notice belatedly that your title says on a Mac, so this may not help much as I believe the tool is Windows only.)

Answer (score 0):

Here a quick-and-dirty python five-liner to convert a SAS .xpt (aka XPORT) file to .csv

```
import pandas as pd
FILE_PATH = "(fully qualified name of directory containing file)"
FILE = "ABC"  # filename itself (without suffix)

# Note: might need to substitute the column name of the index (in quotes) for "None" here

df = pd.read_sas(FILE_PATH + FILE + '.XPT', index=None)

df.to_csv(FILE_PATH + FILE + '.csv')
```

Hopefully this might help someone

Answer (score -1):

JMP runs on MAC and can read sas files. Visit [jmp.com](http://jmp.com/) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

There are two parts to your question
1. Read these files
2. Convert these files
I looked into the link you shared there are no directly downloadable files, but I am assuming that you mean the files for windows.

1. For viewing you can use the folloiwng
   a. SAS Universal viewer: https://support.sas.com/downloads/package.htm?pid=667
   b. Use SAS on mac to directly read the files
2. For conversion you can do the following
   a. Use SAS proc import to export and proc export to export the files feature, 
   b. Use third party softwares, e.g., DBMSCopy for this;
   c. Download trial version of JMP and convert the files to desired format, e.g., CSV/txt etc and get done with it.